# How to extract ARP MAC Address with Vendor Name from PCAP and save to File

Tags: python, python-3.x, wireshark, pcap, dpkt

I need to extract ARP MAC-addresses with vendor names from PCAP-files and save those as a CSV-file. Below code is working fine for source and destination MAC but I need the code to extract the MAC vendor name.

I had used `DPKT` to extract the data from PCAP.

```
from src.arpbasic import mac_addr

s_mac = mac_addr(eth.src)
d_mac = mac_addr(eth.dst)
```

Comment: You can use [Wireshark's database of known manufacturers](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf). Just download the file and do lookups there.

Comment: may there is any method for python which can extract directly from pcap file? and save to csv format?

Comment: A pcap-file does not include resolved vendor names, neither does pcapng afaik. You'll have to do it yourself. There is [maclookup](https://pypi.org/project/maclookup/)

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your time and advise.

Comment: I had checked some codes working for single MAC lookup. actually i would like to lookup list of MAC vendor by Python.